# discover first unused static ip address

Tags: linux, networking

I need to dynamically discover the first unused IP address on 192.168.0.0/24. This is in a small network with a single switch, no host running any dns or dhcp services. Basically every host self assigns a static ip. I need a way (in a RHEL kickstart file - `%post` section) to figure out what is an available static ip address, and then assign it to myself.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
USED_ADDRESSES_ARRAY=()
for address in `nmap -sT 192.168.0.0/24 | grep -B1 "Host is up" | grep 192 | awk '{print $5;}' | awk -F "." '{print $4;}'`
do
    USED_ADDRESSES_ARRAY+=($address)
done

ip_address_to_assign=0    
for target_address in {1..253}
do
  if [ $target_address  -ne ${USED_ADDRESSES_ARRAY[$target_address - 1]} ]
  then
    ip_address_to_assign=$target_address
    break
  fi
done
echo $ip_address_to_assign
cat > /tmp/output.txt << EOF3
DEVICE="eth0"
`grep HWADDR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1`
IPV6INIT="no"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=192.168.0.$ip_address_to_assign
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.254"
EOF3
cat /tmp/output.txt
```

When I like what I have, I'll change the `/tmp/output.txt` references to point to `ifcfg-eth0` and drop it into the `%post` section of the ks.cfg.

Comment: So, does your script work? Why not? What is the expected output and what are you getting? It seems to be working perfectly well as far as I can tell.

Comment: You are effectively re-inventing DHCP...

Comment: I suppose a more appropriate introduction would have been "can you see a way to do this any better?". @LeeHarrison, yes it does seem kind of silly. But there won't ever be DHCP behind this network for organizational reasons.

Comment: why not set machines for DHCP and get APIPA addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it simpler with something like this:

```
 for i in {1..253}; do 
  ping -c 1 192.168.0.$i >/dev/null; 
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
        echo "192.168.0.$i is unused"; 
        break; 
  fi; 
 done
```